# Как использовать Comparator?

Tags: c++

Есть сортировка. Ее надо переделать так, чтобы она работала с Comparator.
Сейчас у меня ошибка:

> Ошибка    C2664   "bool myclass::operator ()(int,int)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "RandomIterator" в "int"

Как это исправить?

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (int i, int j) { return (i < j); }
} myobject;
template <class RandomIterator, class Compare>
void sort(RandomIterator begin, RandomIterator end, Compare comp) {
    int temp{ 0 };

    if (end - begin + 1 > 2) {
        temp = (end - begin + 1) / 3;
        sort(begin, end - temp, comp);
        sort(begin + temp, end, comp);
        sort(begin, end - temp, comp);
    }
    if (comp(end, begin)) {
       std::swap(begin, end);
    }
}

int main() {
    experiment ex;

    int n{ 1000 };
    std::vector<int> c(n);

    sort(c.begin(), c.end(), myclass());
    std::cout << "\nd. Sorted data: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) std::cout << c[i] << ' ';


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы исправить "Comporator" ("композитор" - румынский) на "Comparator" (англ.) и поставить знак вопроса, если Вы задаёте вопрос, а не рассказываете о том, как использовать?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov вы можете сами предложить правку любого (почти) сообщения. А когда достигните репутации в 2000, то сможете вносить правки самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите сравнитель тоже шаблоном. Аргументы могут быть значениями или итераторами. Привёл два способа :

```
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>

template <class RandomIterator>
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (RandomIterator i, RandomIterator j) {
      return ((*i) < (*j)); }
} ;

template <class RandomValue>
struct myclassval {
    bool operator() (RandomValue i, RandomValue j) { 
      return (i < j); }
} ;

template <class RandomIterator, class Compare>
void sort(RandomIterator begin, RandomIterator end, Compare comp) {
    int temp{ 0 };

    if (end - begin + 1 > 2) {
        temp = (end - begin + 1) / 3;
        sort(begin, end - temp, comp);
        sort(begin + temp, end, comp);
        sort(begin, end - temp, comp);
    }
    if (comp(end, begin)) {

       // менять надо значения, а не итераторы
       std::swap(*begin, *end);
    }
}

template <class RandomIterator, class Compare>
void sortval(RandomIterator begin, RandomIterator end, Compare compval) {
    int temp{ 0 };

    if (end - begin + 1 > 2) {
        temp = (end - begin + 1) / 3;
        sortval(begin, end - temp, compval);
        sortval(begin + temp, end, compval);
        sortval(begin, end - temp, compval);
    }
    if (compval(*end, *begin)) {

       // менять надо значения, а не итераторы
       std::swap(*begin, *end);
    }
}

int main() {

    int n{ 1000 };
    std::vector<int> c(n);

    sort(c.begin(), c.end(), myclass<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>());
    sortval(c.begin(), c.end(), myclassval<int>());
    std::cout << "\nd. Sorted data: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) std::cout << c[i] << ' ';


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, вы вызываете

```
comp(end, begin)
```

компаратор для **итераторов**, а описываете его как принимающий значения `int`:

```
bool operator() (int i, int j) { return (i < j); }
```

Может, все же

```
comp(*end, *begin)
```

нет? Да и `swap` ниже - что именно вы хотите обменивать? Значения, на которые указывают итераторы, или сами итераторы?